# How to center the middle child in a Compose Row and make it responsive

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to build a row in Jetpack Compose, with 3 elements, where the first and last elements are "stuck" to either sides, and the middle one stays in the center. The elements **are not all the same width**. It's possible for the first element to be really long, in which case I would like the middle item to move to the right, as much as possible. The images below hopefully illustrate what I mean:

1. All elements fit nicely

[image]

2. The first element is long and pushes the middle item to the right

[image]

3. The first element is super long, pushes the middle item all the way to the right and uses an ellipsis if necessary.

[image]

Wrapping each element in a `Box` and setting each `weight(1f)` helps with the first layout, but it doesn't let the first element to grow if it's long. Maybe I need a custom implementation of a [Row Arrangement?](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement)

Comment: Have you looked at the Row's horizontalArrangement property?  I think that might be what you are looking for with a value of 'SpaceBetween' or 'SpaceEvenly'

Comment: I have, and neither is helpful unfortunately. `SpaceBetween` creates even gaps between elements, which doesn't position the middle element in the center if the elements have unequal widths. `SpaceEvenly` has similar behaviour plus it adds space at the start and at the end too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to get the desired behaviour with a combination of custom implementation of an `Arrangement` and `Modifier.weight`.

I recommend you investigate the implementation of `Arrangement.SpaceBetween` or `Arrangement.SpaceEvenly` to get the idea.

For simplicity, I'm also assuming we'll always have 3 elements to place within the `Row`.

First, we create our own implementation of the [`HorizontalOrVertical` interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement.HorizontalOrVertical):

```kotlin
val SpaceBetween3Responsively = object : Arrangement.HorizontalOrVertical {
    override val spacing = 0.dp

    override fun Density.arrange(
        totalSize: Int,
        sizes: IntArray,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        outPositions: IntArray,
    ) = if (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr) {
        placeResponsivelyBetween(totalSize, sizes, outPositions, reverseInput = false)
    } else {
        placeResponsivelyBetween(totalSize, sizes, outPositions, reverseInput = true)
    }

    override fun Density.arrange(
        totalSize: Int,
        sizes: IntArray,
        outPositions: IntArray,
    ) = placeResponsivelyBetween(totalSize, sizes, outPositions, reverseInput = false)

    override fun toString() = "Arrangement#SpaceBetween3Responsively"
}
```

The `placeResponsivelyBetween` method needs to calculate the correct gap sizes between the elements, given their measured widths, and then place the elements with the gaps in-between.

```kotlin
fun placeResponsiveBetween(
    totalSize: Int,
    size: IntArray,
    outPosition: IntArray,
    reverseInput: Boolean,
) {
    val gapSizes = calculateGapSize(totalSize, size)

    var current = 0f
    size.forEachIndexed(reverseInput) { index, it ->
        outPosition[index] = current.roundToInt()

        // here the element and gap placement happens
        current += it.toFloat() + gapSizes[index]
    }
}
```

`calculateGapSize` has to try and "place" the second/middle item in the centre of the row, if the first element is short enough. Otherwise, set the first gap to 0, and check if there's space for another gap.

```kotlin
private fun calculateGapSize(totalSize: Int, itemSizes: IntArray): List<Int> {
    return if (itemSizes.sum() == totalSize) { // the items take up the whole space and there's no space for any gaps
        listOf(0, 0, 0)
    } else {
        val startOf2ndIfInMiddle = totalSize / 2 - itemSizes[1] / 2

        val firstGap = Integer.max(startOf2ndIfInMiddle - itemSizes.first(), 0)
        val secondGap = totalSize - itemSizes.sum() - firstGap

        listOf(firstGap, secondGap, 0)
    }
}
```

Then we can use `SpaceBetween3Responsively` in our `Row`! Some code edited out for simplicity

```kotlin
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = SpaceBetween3Responsively,
            ) {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false)) {
                    Text(text = "Supercalifragilisticexplialidocious",
                        maxLines = 1,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis)
                }
                Box {
                    // Button
                }
                Box {
                    // Icon
                }
            }
```

`Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false)` is important here for the first element - because it's the only one with assigned `weight`, it forces the other elements to be measured first. This makes sure that if the first element is long, it's truncated/cut to allow enough space for the other two elements (button and icon). This means the correct sizes are passed into `placeResponsivelyBetween` to be placed with or without gaps. `fill = false` means that if the element is short, it doesn't have to take up the whole space it's assigned - meaning there's space for the other elements to move closer, letting the Button in the middle.

Et voila!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to surround the middle element with 2 elements with a weight of 1.

[image: preview]

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        // Left element
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        ) {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.ArrowLeft,
                    contentDescription = "Previous"
                )
            }

            IconButton(
                onClick = { }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.ArrowRight,
                    contentDescription = "Next"
                )
            }

            Text(
                "Overflowing text",
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            )
        }


        // Center element
        Button(
            onClick = { }
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.PlayArrow,
                contentDescription = "Play"
            )
        }

        // Right element
        Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)){
            IconButton(
                onClick = { }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.RestartAlt,
                    contentDescription = "Restart"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the `contentAlignment`. There is no absolute "CenterRight", but that's fine because the right element will go to the left.

[image: preview]

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        // Left element
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Absolute.Right
        ) {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.ArrowLeft,
                    contentDescription = "Previous"
                )
            }

            IconButton(
                onClick = { }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.ArrowRight,
                    contentDescription = "Next"
                )
            }
        }


        // Center element
        Button(
            onClick = { }
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.PlayArrow,
                contentDescription = "Play"
            )
        }

        // Right element
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
        ){
            IconButton(
                onClick = { }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.RestartAlt,
                    contentDescription = "Restart"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TestPreview() {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
        Test()
    }
}
```